# Make new directory using cURL/php

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

After I figured out how to create new directories using cURL, I now want to use it in PHP.

```
curl -k -v "sftp://<username>:<password>@12.34.56.78/subdomains/cdn/"
     -Q "-MKDIR /subdomains/cdn/mynewdir" --ftp-create-dirs
```

I figured out that it should be something like the following, but it still misses some things (cuz it aint working yet):

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "sftp://<username>:<password>@12.34.56.78/subdomains/cdn/mynewdir");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS, TRUE);

$result = curl_exec($ch);

if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
}

curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: "aint working" doesn't really help us understand the problem. Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cURL as an interface to SFTP. It's not really made for that, and it makes for an awkward interface.

Instead, use PHP's native interface to SFTP, which is part of the ssh2 extension. The [`ssh2_sftp_mkdir()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ssh2-sftp-mkdir.php) function will do exactly what you're looking for -- here's the sample code from the documentation:

```
<?php
$connection = ssh2_connect('shell.example.com', 22);
ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
$sftp = ssh2_sftp($connection);

ssh2_sftp_mkdir($sftp, '/home/username/newdir');
/* Or:  mkdir("ssh2.sftp://$sftp/home/username/newdir"); */
?>
```

Comment: This answer assumes I'm able to install the SSH2 extension. I'll believe this works fine, but I wanted to try it with cURL, because it seems possible.

Answer (score 0):

After some further research, I found out that I was doing it the hard way (using curl). The easiest way to create a new directory for me in PHP is just to use [mkdir](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mkdir.php).

Comment: PHP MkDir wouldn't create remote directories on an SFTP server though.

Answer (score 0):

Having just gone through this issue thought I'd share my findings here for the future.

`CURLOPT_FTP_CREATE_MISSING_DIRS` I haven't been able to get to work with current curl

The best and I believe only working solution is do a mkdir (this is from root) in a curl quote command.

So if you wanted to make

*/home/me/x/y*

you would have to make that from root so (in command line)

```
curl sftp://user:pass@me.com -Q "mkdir /home/me/x/y"
```

This remains the same for libcurl but using the POSTQUOTE setopt